# File Picker when required on Windows phone's webApp

Tags: c#, web-applications, windows-phone, filepicker

I'm programming a webApp for Windows Phone. I would like to select a picture from my phone when the browser requests it. For example, if I have to change my profile picture, I would like to select from my gallery. How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have a look at the [How to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Can you share some code showing what you have done so far?

Comment: I don't have a code. I have started this tread because I don't know the code for resolve my problem. Can you help me?